# Polymorphism not working if overloaded functions are being overridden only partially

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

Today I felt like a noob:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(int)=0;
    virtual void foo(int, int) {}
    virtual void bar() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(int) {}
};

void main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.bar(); // works
    d.foo(1); // works
    d.foo(1,2); // compiler error: no matching function call
}
```

I expected `d` to inherit `foo(int, int)` from `Base`, but it does not. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the base functions with the same name are hidden.

You'll need to use `using` for the function you're not overriding:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::foo;
    virtual void foo(int) {}  //this hides all base methods called foo
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called `Name hiding`. You hide `Base::foo(int, int)` by providing `Derived::foo(int)`